# How to get the value of EntityKey?

Tags: entitykey

How to get the value of EntityKey?

I tried:

String x = Customer.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;

String x = Customer.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value.ToString();

String x = Customer.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues;

String x = Customer.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.ToString();

Ended up with:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: On which line? All of them or just one?

Comment: so one of your objects has not been initialized into memory... Go into debug mode and check which object is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you reported that you're getting an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, you might want to check for a `null` reference;

```
String x = (Custormer == null ? null :
              Customer.EntityKey == null ? null :
                Customer.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.Length == 0 ? null :
                  Customer.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value);
```